# scrapy creating a selector from another selector

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

When I create a selector from another selector using xpath, the created selector still contains the full original selector content. See for example

```
original_document = """
    <a>
    <b>
        <c>hello_1</c>
    </b>
    <c>hello_2</c>
    </a>
"""
document_sel = scrapy.Selector(text = original_document)
second_sel = document_sel.xpath('//b')
```

second_sel has correctly been extracted and subset from the original document:

```
print second_sel.extract()
[u'<b>\n        <c>hello_1</c>\n    </b>']
```

But when I try to extract  from second_sel:

```
print second_sel.xpath('//c').extract()
[u'<c>hello_1</c>', u'<c>hello_2</c>']
```

Why is "hello_2" being extracted ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Scrapy documentation: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html in "Working with relative XPaths" it has to be retrieve using ".//"

```
print second_sel.xpath('.//c').extract()
[u'<c>hello_1</c>']
```

Comment: Do you expect a refined answer? e.g. you can get `hello_1` without any tags using  `text()`.